# Shiny app map not connecting properly to radioButtons

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to make an map where selecting different radiobutton options gives you a map of the EU coloured by density. However, when I use input$ to connect the radiobuttons to the server section, it doesn't connect properly. What am I doing wrong?

The data is number of animals per country in 5 columns. When I write the column heading directly into the code in the server section, I get a map showing the relative populations by colour gradations (which is what I want), but when I try to input$ to the radiobuttons it just shows all the countries I have data for as being the same colour (doesn't differentiate colour based on population size). How can I fix the radiobutton-input$ connection?

```
ui<- fluidPage( 
  radioButtons(inputId = "type", "Choose an animal", 
           c("Cat" = "cat_pop",
             "Dog" = "dog_pop",
             "Chicken" = "chicken_pop", 
             "Dairy Cow" = "dcow_pop",
             "Grey Wolf" = "wolf_pop")),
    plotOutput(outputId = "graph")
)


server<- function(input, output) {
  output$graph<- renderPlot({
    EU_base + 
      geom_polygon(data = animalmap, aes(fill = input$type)) +
      geom_polygon(color = "black", fill = NA) +
      theme_bw() +
      ditch_the_axes} + 
      coord_fixed(xlim = c(30, -10),  ylim = c(36, 70), ratio = 1.3)
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

#when I replace aes(fill = cat_pop) then it works properly but then can't be changed with the radiobuttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`aes()` expects unquoted arguments](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_.html), but you are passing a quoted argument when you use `input$type`. Try `aes_string()`

```r
ui<- fluidPage( 
  radioButtons(inputId = "type", "Choose an animal", 
           c("Cat" = "cat_pop",
             "Dog" = "dog_pop",
             "Chicken" = "chicken_pop", 
             "Dairy Cow" = "dcow_pop",
             "Grey Wolf" = "wolf_pop")),
    plotOutput(outputId = "graph")
)


server<- function(input, output) {
  output$graph<- renderPlot({
    EU_base + 
      geom_polygon(data = animalmap, aes_string(fill = input$type)) +
      geom_polygon(color = "black", fill = NA) +
      theme_bw() +
      ditch_the_axes} + 
      coord_fixed(xlim = c(30, -10),  ylim = c(36, 70), ratio = 1.3)
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```